# how event handler (hooking) for every page_Load in web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, web-config, handler

i made a folder in visual studio 2010 **(my folder)** and i have many pages inside that folder base on master and content pages...
i want to hook a class to every `Page_Load` Or `Page_PreInit` of every `content pages` inside that `folder` **except** `master page`!
how can i do that with private web.config inside that folder?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that something like that is possible the way you need it but here are some thoughts.

Initially you must create a class that inherits from `System.Web.UI.Page` and `override` `OnLoad` or `OnPreInit`. Something  like that:

```
    public class MyPage : Page {
     protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
           base.OnLoad(e);
         }
    }
```

Next, you can:

- Either Use the `pageBaseType="typename, assembly"` [attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/950xf363%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) inside `<system.web/pages>`. But this works only for pages that don't have a code-behind file so you need to delete it and also remove the `Inherits` attribute at the top of the aspx (Mark-Up) page.
- Or edit the code-behind file of the pages you want to use your custom class and make them inherit from that.

Comment: thanks for answer / i test option #1 and #2 / option #2 is ok / but in option #1 what can we do about pages with code behind ?

Comment: you are right , option #1 does not work for pages with code behind , i removed cs file and Inherits attribute at the top of the aspx (Mark-Up) page => now it works / but what about pages with code behind?

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom class inheriting from `System.Web.UI.Page` - override `OnLoad` or hook up `page_load` event and provide implementation as per your need.

Supply this class as a base page class [using pageBaseType attribute in pages element](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/06/08/766.aspx) in the  configuration file.

Comment: @VinayC thanks for answer / whould you plz give us some explain about previous comment!

Comment: @MonnLight, djsolid is correct - this approach will work for web sites. The `inherits` attribute from aspx page supersedes `pageBaseType` value - for files with code-behind class, `inherits` attribute points to your code-behind class. The code-behind class will typically mentions the class that it inherits from (which is by default System.Web.UI.Page). So for web applications, you cannot change the base page class using configuration (but you need to edit code-behind file).